# How to access an object in an array stored in a class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I guess this again quite basic, but how do I access an object in an array which belongs to a class?

My class is called NoteBook. In this NoteBook I have an array called tabReference. Imagine I have four objects in this array and would like to access the first at index 0.

I tried

```
int k = 0;    
currentNoteBook.tabReference[objectAtIndex:k];
```

but xCode tells me that objectAtIndex is undeclared. What would be the correct call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the correct way to access an array member in objective c for your example would be:

```
[currentNoteBook.tabReference objectAtIndex:k];
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want access to the object in the class so can also do like this :

```
[self.tabReference objectAtIndex:k];
```